# Trigger function returns: query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a trigger function that verify the result of a query in order to execute a function. The below code returns the error: query has no destination for result data. Despite several attempt to fix it I could not find a solution.

```
BEGIN
WITH u AS (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY observation.observationid) AS obsid,
    observation.observationid,
    observation.resulttime,
    numericvalue.value,
    series.observablepropertyid,
    series.procedureid,
    observableproperty.name,
    lag(numericvalue.value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY observation.observationid) AS prev_value     
   FROM observation
     JOIN numericvalue ON numericvalue.observationid = observation.observationid
     JOIN series ON series.seriesid = observation.seriesid
     JOIN observableproperty ON observableproperty.observablepropertyid = series.observablepropertyid
    WHERE observableproperty.name::text = 'LivelloInvaso'::text 
  ORDER BY observation.observationid DESC
 LIMIT 1)

SELECT value, prev_value FROM u;

IF u.value >= 463
AND u.prev_value < 463

THEN
    perform ___send_mail();
    ELSE RETURN null;   
END IF;
RETURN null;
END;
```

I'm not sure why I'm having this error. What is the problem with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell SELECT into which variable to put the result.

```
DECLARE
    rcd RECORD;
BEGIN
    ...
    SELECT value, prev_value INTO rcd FROM u; 

    IF rcd.value >= 463
    AND rcd.prev_value < 463
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now, this were the lacking passage!